# Can Bot Framework handle Facebook Audio Message

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, chatbot

How can my bot (Bot Framework Microsoft) handle an audio message from facebook.

How it's received in the Post Message in MessagesController? So I can call the SpeechToText API?

Does the data go all the way to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Post controller takes an Activity as an argument.  The Audio message will show up in the Attachment array as a link to the audio location provided by Facebook.  You can pass that to the [Bing Speech API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api). One thing to note that the ContentType provided by Facebook is "video/mp4" (which could be confusing).

Answer (score 2):

You get an attachment of the type "audio/aac". You need to access it via your activity object.

```
var sound = activity.Attachments?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ContentType.Equals("audio/aac"));
```

Now you can easily access the actual message via `sound.ContentUrl` and have a URI to the file, which you then can put into an encoder to convert it to wav. Then you can put it into you Bing speech Api.