# How to access Facebook voice messages in a Bot?

Tags: facebook, audio, bots, botframework

I'm currently trying to get the audio/voice messages from user into my bot.
I'm using MS Bot Framework and I know voice messages are stored as an attachment and in the format "video/mp4" according to this post, [Can Bot Framework handle Facebook Audio Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918731/can-bot-framework-handle-facebook-audio-message). But I don't know how to access the attachment the right way.

```
var sound = activity.Attachments?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ContentType.Equals("video/mp4"));

if (sound != null) {
                    await context.PostAsync("I have received sound");
                    context.Done(context);
                }
```

Unfortunately `sound` was always empty.

So how can I access the sound attachment the right way? And what Nuget-Package would you recommend for encoding it to "audio/wave" format for the Bing Speech Api?

Comment: I have to correct me, the format of Facebook voice messages is "audio/aac"

Answer (score 0):

```
var audio = Context.Activity.Attachments?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ContentType.Equals("audio/aac"));
```